# Jest pass a mocked class to a constructor

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

Let's say I have

```
class A {
  constructor(classB) {

  }
}

class B {

}
```

How do I instantiate `class A` in my test, and pass a mocked `class B` to it? Basically I want to do

```
a = new A(mockedClassB);
```

To be specific, my question is about how to create `mockedClassB` so I can pass this to the A constructor.

Comment: What's the issue with doing `new A(mockedClassB)`?

Comment: Or are you asking how to create a mocked class be [in jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks) ?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I'm asking how to create `mockedClassB` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution:

`a.js`:

```js
export default class A {
  classB;
  constructor(classB) {
    this.classB = classB;
  }

  getName() {
    return this.classB.getName();
  }
}
```

`b.js`:

```js
export default class B {
  getName() {
    return 'real name from b';
  }

  // add a new method later
  getAge() {
    return 23;
  }
}
```

`a.test.js`:

```js
import A from './a';
import B from './b';
jest.mock('./b');

describe('61596704', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const mockedClassBInstance = new B();
    mockedClassBInstance.getName.mockReturnValueOnce('mocked name from b');
    const a = new A(mockedClassBInstance);
    const actual = a.getName();
    expect(actual).toEqual('mocked name from b');
  });

  it('getAge method of B should be mocked as well', () => {
    const mockedClassBInstance = new B();
    jest.isMockFunction(mockedClassBInstance.getAge);
  });
});
```

unit test results:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/61596704/a.test.js (8.913s)
  61596704
    ✓ should pass (3ms)
    ✓ getAge method of B should be mocked as well (1ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.486s
```

Comment: Ya that's an issue. Once I add a new method to class B, I need to come back and update this test call. I was hoping there would be the equivalent of Java's Mockito so I could mock the entire class instead of individually mocking each method

Comment: @Kousha Updated answer, you can use `jest.mock()` or `jest.doMock()` to mock all methods of class